# Resize Webpart zone without sharepoint designer in SP2010

Tags: web-part-zone

I have a left webpart zone including webparts with smaller widths. I have then a wide blank space on the right part of the webpart zone. 
I would like to find a way to reduce the width of the left webpart zone to fit my webpart width. I have no access to Sharepoint designer so would need to be around html/css using CEWP.
Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

The layout itself is an HTML table. You can address the cells/rows/columns of that table via CSS.

Assuming your current layout is:

```
 ______________________________________
|                                      |
|               Header                 |
|______________________________________|
|                         |            |
|      Body               |Right Column|
|_________________________|____________|
```

In your CEWP, add the following CSS rules to make Body and Right Column equal in width:

```
<style>
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1){
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Adjust the width-value to whatever value fits your requirements.